# Confusing error using factorial with numpy or scipy arrays

Tags: numpy, scipy, factorial

The following code identifies a list of prime numbers

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
for x in range(20, 50):
    print(x, math.factorial(x-1) % x)
```

the output is

```
20 0
21 0
22 0
23 22
24 0
25 0
26 0
27 0
28 0
29 28
30 0
31 30
32 0
33 0
34 0
35 0
36 0
37 36
38 0
39 0
40 0
41 40
42 0
43 42
44 0
45 0
46 0
47 46
48 0
49 0
```

The residue of the calculation is non zero for every prime.
When I try to do the same calculation with arrays, my results are different.

```
arr = np.arange(20,50)
modFactArr = factorial(arr-1) % arr
print(np.column_stack((arr,modFactArr)),'\n\n')

smodFactArr=scipy.special.factorial(arr-1) % arr
print(np.column_stack((arr,smodFactArr)),'\n\n')
```

gives

```
[[20.  0.]
 [21.  0.]
 [22.  0.]
 [23. 22.]
 [24.  0.]
 [25. 22.]
 [26. 16.]
 [27. 11.]
 [28. 12.]
 [29. 16.]
 [30. 24.]
 [31.  8.]
 [32.  0.]
 [33. 18.]
 [34. 16.]
 [35. 33.]
 [36. 20.]
 [37. 12.]
 [38. 20.]
 [39. 10.]
 [40.  0.]
 [41. 25.]
 [42. 26.]
 [43.  6.]
 [44.  4.]
 [45.  3.]
 [46. 36.]
 [47. 40.]
 [48.  0.]
 [49. 12.]] 


[[20.  0.]
 [21.  0.]
 [22.  0.]
 [23. 22.]
 [24.  0.]
 [25. 22.]
 [26. 16.]
 [27. 11.]
 [28. 12.]
 [29. 16.]
 [30. 24.]
 [31.  8.]
 [32.  0.]
 [33. 18.]
 [34. 16.]
 [35. 33.]
 [36. 20.]
 [37. 12.]
 [38. 20.]
 [39. 10.]
 [40.  0.]
 [41. 25.]
 [42. 26.]
 [43.  6.]
 [44.  4.]
 [45.  3.]
 [46. 36.]
 [47. 40.]
 [48.  0.]
 [49. 12.]]
```

Notice now that numbers like 26,27,28,etc are giving residuals now. Is this an error with my code? or is there a reason that scipy and numpy are doing modulo arithmetic differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because of `np.dtype`. You just have overflow of `np.int64` while native python `int` can not be overflowed.

Comment: really? I would have thought they overflow at the same large values

Comment: @aquagremlin. Python int objects are infinite precision. It will literally allocate as much memory to hold the number as necessary. Array elements are fixed by necessity.

Comment: These are not int64, they're float64.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> With `exact=False` the factorial is **approximated** using the gamma function

`exact=False` is the default.

You can tell this is being approximated because the result is a float (hence the `.0`), and floats are not able to store integral results accurately beyond 2**53.